# split large text file into chunks by lines containing a specific character

Tags: bash

I am trying to chunk a large text file (~27 Gb) into a series of smaller files, where the break points are defined by a subheader each of which contains the same symbol (in this case '@').

So the following large file:

```
@auniquestring
dataline1
dataline2
...
dataline33456
@aseconduniquestring
dataline33458
dataline33459
...
dataline124589
@athirdunqiuestring
dataline124591
dataline124592
...
```

...becomes:

1st file:

```
@auniquestring
dataline1
dataline2
...
dataline33456
```

2nd file:

```
@aseconduniquestring
dataline33458
dataline33459
...
dataline124589
```

3rd file:

```
@athirdunqiuestring
dataline124591
dataline124592
...
```

etc

I've tried things like `sed -n '/@/,/@/p' myfile` but it outputs everything at once, and misses the contents of every other subheader. Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Have you tried `csplit`? Like `csplit -z file /@/ '{*}'`

Comment: thank you, that's what I was looking for. Slight tweak to your line of code to make it work: ```csplit -z file '/@/' '{*}'```. Is there a trivial way to have the subheaders that contain the '@' symbol to be the file names?

Comment: in bash5 it works without quoting `/@/`. no, you need awk for that, tweak the script james posted below and it'll do

Answer (score 2):

Using awk (NOTICE IT WILL CREATE FILES NAMED `file[0-9]+.txt`):

```
$ awk '
BEGIN {
    file="file0.txt"               # just in case
}
/^@/ {                             # when record starts with @
    close(file)                    # close previous file
    file=sprintf("file%d.txt",++f) # generate next filename
}
{
    print > file                   # output to generated filename
}' file
```

Sample output:

```
$ cat file1.txt
@auniquestring
dataline1
dataline2
...
dataline33456
```

Answer (score 0):

Modern Bash versions can compare regular expressions.

```
#! /bin/bash
n=1
while read -r line; do
  if [[ $line =~ ^@ ]]; then
    exec >file$((n++))
  fi
  printf "%s\n" "$line"
done
```